# Word Wrapping on a web page

Tags: vb.net, web

I am currently working on creating a web page using .NET 2008. We are getting information from a database and when displaying it I cannot get it to wrap underneath. For example:

```
 2231 Question 1
 2232 Mechanical Engineering Technologists and Technicians 
 2233 Industrial Engineering and Manufacturing Technologists 
 and Technicians 
 2234 Question 4
```

In 2233 how can I get it to go underneath to look like this:

```
 2231 Question 1
 2232 Mechanical Engineering Technologists and Technicians 
 2233 Industrial Engineering and Manufacturing Technologists 
      and Technicians 
 2234 Question 4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would structure your HTML in the following manner:

```
<div class="qNumber">2231</div>
<div class="qContent">Question 1</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="qNumber">2232</div>
<div class="qContent">Mechanical Engineering Technologists and Technicians</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="qNumber">2233</div>
<div class="qContent">Industrial Engineering and Manufacturing Technologists and Technicians </div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="qNumber">2234</div>
<div class="qContent">Question 4</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And your CSS would be the following:

```
.qNumber { float: left; width: 40px; }
.qContent { width: 350px; padding-left: 40px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Obviously tweak the number to your liking :)

Comment: +1: This is the better way I was alluding to in my answer.  CSS FTW!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a better way, but this can be done cheaply and quickly with tables.

```
<table>
<tr><td>2231</td><td>Question 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2232</td><td>Mechanical Engineering Technologists and Technicians</td></tr> 
<tr><td>2233</td><td>Industrial Engineering and Manufacturing Technologists and Technicians</td></tr> 
<tr><td>2234</td><td>Question 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Well, I tried to implement it in markdown, but it didn't like it.

-Adam